# Death Stranding kids trophy meaning?

Tags: death-stranding

[image]

Could you tell me what this trophy image has to do with customizations? It looks a car tire to me

Comment: What this image means for customizations? It looks a tire...

Answer (score 1):

That is the [The Custom Kid](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/death-stranding/trophy/285621-the-custom-kid.html) trophy.

> You will unlock this through normal gameplay. There are plenty of customizations you can apply to either an upgraded structure, your backpack, or custom colors for your gear (suit, glasses, hat, vehicles etc.) and you will unlock many of them as you play through the story orders and develop your star ratings with the facilities.

There's no real stated logic behind it, but [this fellow](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1190460/discussions/0/5704366794249364708/?tscn=1637102314#c3196988242366492384) thinks it might be "the ball that is used in some PCC structures, but removed from the little pillar it normally sits on top of."

[image: Image of PCC structure]

Comment: I don’t understand the meaning of the image,

Comment: Is it a tire???

Comment: Ah, that I have not been able to figure out. It's obviously an object on a shelf, and the "fan blades" in the center make me think of the Odradak when retracted, but I haven't found an image that matches.